# Implementation of quicksort with pivot as median of first, middle and last elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-science, quicksort, median

```
from sys import stdin,stdout

def readln(): 
    return stdin.readline().rstrip()

def outln(n): 
    stdout.write(str(n)) stdout.write("\n")

m = 10 
n = random.sample(range(1, 1000000),m)

def particao(n, inicio, fim): 
lista = [] 
primeiro = n[inicio] 
lista.append(primeiro) 
pos_meio = (inicio+fim)//2 
meio = n[pos_meio] 
lista.append(meio) 
ultimo = n[fim] 
lista.append(ultimo) 
lista.sort() 
pivot = lista[1] 
if lista[1] == primeiro: 
    indice_pivot = inicio 
if lista[1] == meio: 
    indice_pivot = pos_meio 
if lista[1] == ultimo: 
    indice_pivot = fim

while inicio < fim:
    while inicio < len(n) and n[inicio] <= pivot:
        inicio+=1

    while n[fim] > pivot:
        fim-=1

    if inicio < fim:
        hold1 = n[inicio]
        n[inicio] = n[fim]
        n[fim] = hold1

hold2 = n[indice_pivot]
n[indice_pivot] = n[fim]
n[fim] = hold2
return fim

def quicksort(n, inicio, fim): 
    if inicio < fim: 
        part = particao(n, inicio, fim) 
        quicksort(n, inicio, part-1) 
        quicksort(n, part+1, fim)

quicksort(n,0,len(n)-1) 
print(n)
```

I expected the final result to be sorted but most of the times it is not sorted, i tried with an  array of 10 elements but it should be done with 1000+, i think it's an error with the pivot but i tried everything i know and could and wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: Debugging is a good place to start. If you think your pivot code is wrong, try feeding it small test cases and see if you find one where it gives the wrong results. Then trace through it line-by-line (either using a debugger, or by adding print statements) and find the first place where has gives unexpected behavior

Comment: @rcgldr i get "maximum recurssion depth error"

Comment: @RodrigoSantos - I deleted my last comment, looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but partition function is included in quicksort, as sometimes i = j+2 in the code below when a partition step is done. This is a post increment | decrement version of Hoare partition scheme.

```
import random

def quicksort(n, inicio, fim): 
    if(inicio >= fim):
        return
    meio = (inicio + fim)//2
    if(n[inicio] > n[fim]):
        n[inicio], n[fim] = n[fim], n[inicio]
    if(n[inicio] > n[meio]):
        n[inicio], n[meio] = n[meio], n[inicio]
    if(n[fim] < n[meio]):
        n[fim], n[meio] = n[meio], n[fim]
    pivot = n[(inicio + fim)//2]
    i = inicio
    j = fim
    while (i <= j):
        while n[i] < pivot:
            i+=1
        while n[j] > pivot:
            j-=1
        if i <= j:
            n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]
            i+=1
            j-=1
    quicksort(n, inicio, j);
    quicksort(n, i, fim);

m = 10 
n = random.sample(range(1, 1000000),m)
quicksort(n,0,len(n)-1)
print(n)
```